# ASP.NET MVC 4 Zip Code Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I am looking for a attribute for Zip Code Validation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip Code is Required")]
[ZipCode]
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

I know this doesn't work, but this is what I am looking for.

Can anyone Help

I need the Zip for just USA

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention that.  I will add it to the description above.

Comment: Zip code validation depends on the country. Using property attributes is the wrong approach, since they cannot accept input from multiple properties to do the validation.  Just do the validation in the controller.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use a Regex. Try something like this.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip is Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip")]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
[RegularExpression("(^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\\d{1}$)", ErrorMessage = "Zip code is invalid.")] // US or Canada
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip Code is Required.")]
public String ZipCode { set; get; }
```

Comment: Your answer should contain some explanation and not code only.

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer? It is more complex and as far as I can tell it doesn't work. Why are we referencing letters at all?